# UPDATE 2 columns using MERGE having source conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge, group-by

SQL SERVER 2014

I need to update two columns in TargetTable with values from SourceTable

SourceTbl

```
PersonNr |   Block  |   BlockReason |
---------|----------|---------------|
000001   |   1      |   abuse       | 
000001   |   1      |   age         | 
000001   |   0      |   memo        | 
000002   |   1      |   age         | 
000002   |   0      |               | 
000003   |   0      |               | 
000003   |   0      |               | 
000004   |   1      |   behaviour   | 
000005   |   0      |               |
```

TargetTable

```
PersonNr |   Block  |   BlockReason |
---------|----------|---------------|
000001   |   0      |               | 
000001   |   0      |               | 
000002   |   0      |               | 
000002   |   0      |               | 
000004   |   1      |               | 
000005   |   0      |               |
```

Result needed:

```
PersonNr |   Block  |   BlockReason |
---------|----------|---------------|
000001   |   1      |   abuse       | 
000001   |   1      |   abuse       | 
000002   |   1      |   age         | 
000002   |   1      |   age         | 
000004   |   1      |   behaviour   |
000005   |   0      |               |
```

It is not relevant which `BlockReason` Person 1 gets, 
as far as it's one from a row where `Block` = '1'.

I've tried this pretty straight-forward update :

```
UPDATE
    src
SET
    src.Block = '1', 
    src.BlockReason = targ.BlockReason
FROM
    SourceTbl src
INNER JOIN
    TargetTable targ
ON 
    src.PersonNr= targ.PersonNr
WHERE src.Block = '1'
```

But ended up with faulty result-rows where Block and Reason are updated separately :

```
PersonNr |   Block  |   BlockReason |
---------|----------|---------------|
000001   |  1       |   memo        |
```

Next I've tried :

```
MERGE INTO TargetTable AS TGT
USING
(
  SELECT Block, BlockReason, PersonNr
  FROM SourceTbl
 GROUP BY Block, BlockReason, PersonNr
) AS SRC
  ON 
    SRC.PersonNr= TGT.PersonNr AND 
    SRC.Block= '1' 
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET TGT.Block= SRC.Block, TGT.BlockReason= SRC.BlockReason;
```

Got the error

`The MERGE statement attempted to UPDATE or DELETE the same row more than once. This happens when a target row matches more than one source row. A MERGE statement cannot UPDATE/DELETE the same row of the target table multiple times. Refine the ON clause to ensure a target row matches at most one source row, or use the GROUP BY clause to group the source rows.`

Any help? Hugely appreciated! Truly. Totally.

Comment: Your `UPDATE` looks *generally* correct, except with source and target confused. (Should be targetting, well, target, but still correct to be consulting source's block column)

Comment: @Kaptah What's the primary key of your table?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your query is that it gives duplicate values and it's trying to update the same record more than once.And the `GROUP BY` in the subquery doesn't make any sense since you are not using any aggregate function.

Let's take an id(say 1) and check what's going wrong with your query.

```
src.PersonNr |   src.Block  |   src.BlockReason | tgt.PersonNr |   tgt.Block  |   tgt.BlockReason |
-------------|--------------|-------------------|--------------
    000001   |   1          |   abuse           | 000001       |       0      |                   |         
    000001   |   1          |   age             | 000001       |       0      |                   | 
    000001   |   1          |   abuse           | 000001       |       0      |                   |
    000001   |   1          |   age             |  000001      |       0      |                   |
```

Your query will give you the above result and try to update targettable 2 times for each record once with abuse and next with age.

You can try the below query:

```
MERGE INTO TargetTable AS TGT
USING
(
 SELECT Block, BlockReason, PersonNr
 FROM(
       SELECT Block, BlockReason, PersonNr,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PersonNr  ORDER BY [YourPrimaryKey]) RN
       FROM SourceTbl ) X
 WHERE X.RN=1
) AS SRC
  ON 
    SRC.PersonNr= TGT.PersonNr AND 
    SRC.Block= '1' 
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET TGT.Block= SRC.Block, TGT.BlockReason= SRC.BlockReason;
```

Comment: Tried it with correction:  `FROM SourceTbl ) X WHERE
 X.RN=1`. Seems to work :)

Comment: @Kaptah Sorry..That was a typo..missed `WHERE`.Thanks for pointing out.Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have duplicates in your data. Add another (or more than one) column to the `ON` clause of the `MERGE` that will help identify exactly **one record** or find a way to remove duplicates before merging.

Answer (score 0):

The `UPDATE` should be something like this:

```
UPDATE
    targ
SET
    Block = '1', 
    BlockReason = src.BlockReason
FROM
    SourceTbl src
INNER JOIN
    TargetTable targ
ON 
    src.PersonNr= targ.PersonNr
WHERE src.Block = '1'
```

Since we're only using rows from `SourceTbl` where `Block` is `1`, it should not be possible for a row *affected by this update* to end up with a reason which had a `Block` of `0`.

There is still the general issue that this is non-deterministic in cases where multiple rows from `SourceTbl` are joined to one row in `TargetTbl`, but since you've indicated that determinism isn't required here, it shouldn't result in a problem.